# Create a menu for each page of the application

Tags: android, menu, tabs

I'm developping an Android application. I don't do that from scratch, but from existing source given by the former developper.
I've a menu at the main page, with 4 tabs, like that :

```
public class MenuGen extends TabActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        onLoading();
    }
```

and so on. But after clicking on some elements of the view displayed under each tab, the menu desapear (that's normal).
Is there an easy way to make it "stay" ? To make it permanent on each views of the application ? I don't know if i'm clear, but i'd like to have a permanent 4 tabs clickable menu for my application. How to do that ?

Comment: I guess  you can   implement  onCreateOptionsMenu() on each   fragment  activity.   have  u tried   it..

Comment: Thaks for the idea, I think i'm gonna use it

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that the menu will be open always. When it loose its focus it will hide. 
As an alternative approach you can create buttons to keep it visible all times.

Here is another question of similar type. Check it

[Keep Android menu open at all times: onOptionsMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545420/keep-android-menu-open-at-all-times-onoptionsmenu)

Comment: Indeed, the menu isn't always visible... But that solution is, in my case, acceptable. Nevertheless, thanks for the link !